# Allow (“null”) to access your SoundCloud account

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I am currently trying to register a new client application. I have registered the app and input MyApp://oauth as stated in the docs

I changed the appropriate things in my .plist file and added the clientID and secret and the above redirectURL into my iOS initialization code in the AppDelegate:

```
[SCSoundCloud setClientID:@"..."

                   secret:@"..."

              redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MyApp://oauth"]];
```

However, for some reason, even after doing all of this, I still get `Allow (“null”) to access your SoundCloud account` in the SCLoginViewController.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the your app name in that place SC UI uses CFBundleDisplayName from your info.plist.

You can add and get rid of "(null)".